# How to get my bash alias to run when I open terminal

Tags: bashrc, bash-alias

I setup a bash alias to run `neofetch` in `.bash-alias` but the only way to get it to run is to `source` it in every new terminal window. How can I get it to actually run when the terminal starts/opens?

**EDIT:**

it's worth mentioning that I added the alias to the `bashrc` file and when I open a new terminal I get command not found.

---

I added this to my `bashrc` file

`source .bash_alias`
`neofetch`

Comment: More details please: copy and pate the relevant error, and the relevant section of your bashrc

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my `bashrc` file

`source .bash_alias`
`neofetch`

Comment: I'm confused. So adding the line fixed the problem? If so, please indicate this in your answer (like "The issue was solved by adding this to my `bashrc`: ...") and remove the edit from your question. If it did not fix the problem, then remove this answer (it doesn't answer any question that was originally asked here) and edit your question with more information. Feel free to copy-paste everything that appeared in the terminal after opening it like Glenn suggested. Nothing is achieved by commenting on egos of other users, or by getting angry because someone wasn't able to help you.

Comment: Yes put those lines at the bottom of your .bashrc file